# How to display users account separated by ';'?

Tags: powershell

I do regular user checks and occasionally some users have privileged accounts. The attribute that allows me to validate if the standard user has a privileged account is the "comment" attribute. I would like to know how to display the result of the accounts on the same line, separated by ';'

```
$LoginID = (Read-Host "Please type the USER's Login ID").Trim()


### Check if the user has a priviledge account ###
$admUser = foreach($user in $LoginID){

Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(comment=$($user))" -searchbase "OU=Privileged,OU=Accounts,DC=contoso,DC=com" -Properties name, samaccountname
}

$Accounts = if($admUser) {Write-host "The user contains a regular account and a privileged account:" $($admUser.SamAccountName -join ';')$($LoginID)}else{(Write-Host "The user has only a regular account $($LoginID)")}


$Accounts
```

Comment: Why would you loop over a single input string `$LoginID`? Or do you mean someone types in a series of login names separated by a semi-colon? (you're not splitting or even testing the input..) Then you capture the results of the foreach loop in variable `$admUser` but next you treat **that** as a single item, not a possible array..

Comment: I usually use string.Join :  $array = @("A", "B", "C") Write-Host ([string]::Join(";", $array))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Accounts = if($admUser) {"$($admUser.SamAccountName + ';')$($LoginID)"}else{$(Write-Host "The user has only a regular account $($LoginID)")}
```

You can join strings with +

You can also
Write-Host -NoNewline
For output with no new line.  I suggest breaking up your one liner to populate strings then write-host the strings with the -nonewline option.